# How to remove "Main Menu" title from Stark Theme

Tags: routes, theming

I want to have just the main menu list elements displayed through only the stark theme and I can't seem to figure out where I should go to delete the title "Main Menu" that is above the main menu elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `admin/structure/blocks`, find out the `Main menu`, click `configure`, and set title to `<none>`. This should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide it. Based on [Stark's documentation](http://drupal.org/project/stark), there isn't styling at all, so you would have to add a class to it. I assume you have a custom theme based on Stark. If not, [check the documentation on how to do it](http://drupal.org/node/394612).

Comment: I'm just starting from scratch. I want to avoid hiding content. I would like to find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance/Stark/Options and uncheck Main menu in the Toggle Display section