# Remove main menu title from page

Tags: theming

Hi i'm just starting out with Drupal, Have what I think is a really simple question and it has been asked a lot but the answer dont work for me.

I am using the Stark theme to start to buid a theme. I am trying to remove the main menu text from above the menu, please see [image: pic.]

I have tried [How to remove "Main Menu" title from Stark Theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66196/how-to-remove-main-menu-title-from-stark-theme) but this does not work, infact if I remove the block from admin/structure/blocks the menu still shows.

Does any one know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For blocks, **Title** fields is optional so it is not required to enter. However
**Description** field is mandatory to enter but it displays in the admin side listing only.

So you can keep title blank or use `<none>` as Patrick mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers suggest is valid for most themes or at least for those themes that render the main menu via a block, but the Stark theme doesn't.

The Stark theme renders the main menu fixed through it's template files and there are other themes that do it that way.

Furthermore Stark is made for demonstration and debugging purposes:

> The Stark theme is provided for demonstration purposes; it uses Drupal's default
>   HTML markup and CSS styles. It can be used as a troubleshooting tool to
>   determine whether module-related CSS and JavaScript are interfering with a more
>   complex theme, and can be used by designers interested in studying Drupal's
>   default markup without the interference of changes commonly made by more complex
>   themes.

So I wouldn't recommend it as as a normal theme. If you wan't to create a subtheme there are better options.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct theme tab selected when you go to `/admin/structure/block`

Then edit the block and set the block title to `<none>`

Flush your caches at `/admin/config/development/performance`